# Filter column from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below method to filter some columns from dataset. It's working fine while i put the columns manually. I ll try to do it dynamically while am giving the column name dynamically based on datatable column.

```
string StrColumn = "FLD_ID#FLD_CNTRY_NAME";
string[] ArrayColumns = StrColumn.Split('#');
string Column = string.Empty;
const string quote = "\"";
for (int i = 0; i < ArrayColumns.Length; i++)
{
    Column = Column + quote + ArrayColumns[i].ToString() + quote + ",";
}

DTblData = DTblData.DefaultView.ToTable(false, Column);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last "," from your `Column` variable before sorting. Also, I believe  `Column` should look like `"FLD_ID,FLD_CNTRY_NAME"` where by your code it turns out like `""FLD_ID","FLD_CNTRY_NAME""`

Comment: Did you try removing the quotes?